Define JS function in collocated js file and pass that function to be called from different JS file
I am trying to find best way to call some JS function that I declared from external JS file by its name. I am able to make it work using the following approach:
# define function at window level in external example_scripts.js file
window.some_function = function(params) => { ... };

#import example_scripts.js file in app.razor
<script src="_content/MyProject/example_scripts.js"></script>

# here we have some component where we pass name of JS function
# internally it will use JS Interop to call some other JS function from external project
# and pass the name of the JS function we declared to call
<MyComponent Script="some_function" />

# in another JS file in another project we call that function by its name stored in script property
window[script].call(null, params);

This works. Is there a way to make this work by using JS collocated file? The way I underwstood how it works from this document, collocated js files allows us to properly organize js files and avoids step of importing them. However, I am unable to make this work.
If I don't import js file, when debugging the app I do not see anywhere this function/file generated (in Developer Tools -> Sources). If I publish the app, then I can see js file generated in bin/Release/{TARGET FRAMEWORK MONIKER}/publish/wwwroot/{PATH}/{COMPONENT}.razor.js, but it still cannot find it.
Anyone has any idea how to properly declare JS function in collocated js file, so that I can latter call it by name in another JS file?

To call a JavaScript function declared in a collocated JS file from another JS file in a Blazor project, ensure the function is defined globally in the collocated .razor.js file, which Blazor should automatically load. In your Blazor component, use JS Interop to invoke the function by its name. If you need to call this function from another JS file, make sure both files are correctly loaded in your application and use the window object to reference the function
